# Communication between Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, communication

I'm doing an Eclipse RCP aplication. I have created a new Launch Configuration and a view. When I run the launch configuration, I get a set of results and I want to sent those results to the view.

In this moment, I create a new event which contains the results:

```
  BundleContext ctx = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(TraditionalLaunchConfigurationDelegate.class).getBundleContext();
  ServiceReference<EventAdmin> ref = ctx.getServiceReference(EventAdmin.class);
  EventAdmin eventAdmin = ctx.getService(ref);
  Map<String, Results> properties = new HashMap<String, Results>();
  properties.put("MUTATIONRESULTS",  //$NON-NLS-1$
                    results);


  Event event = new Event("mutationcommunication/asyncEvent", properties); //$NON-NLS-1$

  eventAdmin.postEvent(event);
```

The view is listening. When the launch configuration sends the event, the view catches it and shows the results.

The problem is that it works when the view is instantiate. If I don't open manually the view, it doesn't exist, and it doesn't receive anything.

A solution may be open programatically the view, but

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getViewRegistry().find("ID").createView();
```

doesn't work.

Is there a way to send elements to a view and, if the view doesn't exist, which creates a new instance?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("id");
```

to show the view (it will created if it is not already shown).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I knew this method, but it throws a null pointer exception. I don't know if I must registry the plugin's id or something similar.

Comment: Which bit is giving null? The Workbench, active workbench window and active page can all potentially be null.

Comment: The active workbench is null, and I don't know why. When I run my Eclipse RCP, it opens a new Eclipse with all my plug-ins, and apparently it works well.

Comment: If you are using your own application (implementing `IApplication`) you will have to call `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench`

Comment: Sorry, I said it wrong! It isn't an Eclipse RCP application (I don't implement IApplication). It is only a plugin which contains a view (the activator extends AbstractUIPlugin and my view extends ViewPart).

Comment: I fix it! The problem is that the launch configuration isn't a active run, and I need a Display to use PlatformUI...
I find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265174/nullpointerexception-in-platformui-getworkbench-getactiveworkbenchwindow-get).

Thanks @greg-449, you give me the track with the active workbench null. I thank that Eclipse didn't find my plugin id.